# Test Simulate Turn Off Network iPad Testers iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have an app that needs to be tested for certain rare conditions involving the network dying at precise times, which occasionally happens in actual use, but is difficult to test for. As a developer, I simulate this by putting in break points disabling my internet, then continuing on with the test and this works OK.

Is there a solution available for iPad testers? I would love testers who download the app to be able to test these conditions. Does anyone have any experience with this that could shed some light on the best way to set it up?

I'm thinking I could have code at the spots of interest for that build and then add a field to settings like 'delay fetches' testers could turn on before running the app. This would give them enough time to go to settings and turn off their internet then return to the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPad and iPhone users can use `Network Link Conditioner` to simulate different network states, for example, with high latency DNS or 3G/Edge speed. It located in `Settings->Developer->Network Link Conditioner`.

Comment: As an addition to Artem Novichkov answer -  if you want to simulate different network states on Simulator, for Xcode 8 `Network Link Conditioner` is a part of Additional Tools package which you get [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?q=Additional%20Tools).

Comment: I really would prefer something more manual that the tester could do, rather than just an overall simulate bad network, but this answer is still pretty good